# How to avoid showing the selected option in bootstrap multiselect?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

How to show the instead of selected value option 1.3 I want to show some other text as Options as default whenever you selected any other text.

```
<select id="example-dropRight" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Option 1.1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 1.2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 1.3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 2.1</option>
    <option value="5">Option 2.2</option>
    <option value="6">Option 2.3</option>
</select>
```

Image:[image: bootstrap]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery like this to override the text.

```js
 $('#example-dropRight').multiselect({
   onChange: function(option, checked) {
     $('.multiselect-selected-text').text('OnChange Text');
   }
 });

$('.multiselect-selected-text').text('OnLoad Text');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>

<select id="example-dropRight" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">Option 1.1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 1.2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 1.3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 2.1</option>
  <option value="5">Option 2.2</option>
  <option value="6">Option 2.3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: At default load i am not getting OnLoad Text, i am getting **None seelcted ** how to change this

Comment: Does $('.multiselect-selected-text').text('OnLoad Text'); happen after you initialize the multiselect? If it happens before, nothing will happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in "buttonText" configuration in multiselect().

```js
$('#example-dropRight').multiselect({
      buttonText: function(options) {
          return "Search or select";
          // you can show the number of selected options
          // return "(" + options.length + ") options selected";
      }
});
```

Reference: http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-buttonText